# getter and setter to fetch value from array

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have the below code:

```js
String[] arg= {product,file,name};
APICall.setter(arg);
```

Then i am using below two methods as getter and setter to fetch value from the above String :

```js
private static String fileFetcher;
public static void setter(String[] arg) {
    fileFetcher=arg[1];

}

public static String getter() {
    return fileFetcher;
}
```

Now my aim is to fetch the `file` value from the above `String[]` which is in `arg[1]`.
from the above code the method `getter()` should hold the value.So that I may call `getter()` in any place I want. But it returns `null`.

Comment: Can you show us the declarations and initializations of the variables product, file and name which you use to initialize the arg array? Perhaps they are null?

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for the response. Even when I change :String[] arg= {product,"abc",name}; It still returns null.

Answer (score 1):

You get null because `fileFetcher` is not assigned with any value, neither did you invoke the setter to assign a value to `fileFetcher`.

Since `fileFetcher` has not been initialized and has no values assigned to it. It returns you `null` (default String value).

Make sure you invoke the setter() first:

```
//for example
String[] arg = {"product name", "filename", "name"};
YourClass.setter(arg);
System.out.println(YourClass.getter());
```

By the way, your design seems a little odd to me as you have made all members `static`.